# scraping ecommerce site with python

Tags: python, python-requests

i am creating a telegram bot when u send any product link(from myntra,amazon,flipkart). when ever its price get down then it will send a msg to the user so this is my code to scrape price from flipkart and myntra

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


URL = 'https://www.myntra.com/sports-sandals/roadster/roadster-men-charcoal-grey-sports- 
sandals/9024251/buy'

head = {"user_agents":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like 
  Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=head)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")

name = str(BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')).split(".")
test_name = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser').get_text()

if "flixcart" in name:
    title = soup.find(class_={"_35KyD6"}).get_text()
    price = soup.find(class_={"_1vC4OE _3qQ9m1"}).get_text()
    print(title)
    print(price)

if "myntra" in name:
    price = soup.find(class_={"pdp-price"})
    name = soup.find(class_={"pdp-name"})
    #title = soup.find("div class=\"pdp-price-info\"")
    print(price)
```

here code can extract price and name from flipkart but for myntra
in 'price' and 'name' it shows none type
I want to get the name as highlighted in image

[image: I want to get the name as highlighted in image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Data of your page filled dynamically using `Javascript` from `JSON`. But `JSON` does not load through the `XHR`. You can find `JSON` is in `HTML` and you can extract `JSON` using `Regex` and convert `JSON` to `Dictionary`.

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.myntra.com/sports-sandals/roadster/roadster-men-charcoal-grey-sports-sandals/9024251/buy'
headers = {"user_agents":'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.88 Safari/537.36'}

response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

match = re.findall(r"<script>window.__myx = (.+?)</script>", response.text)

json_data = json.loads(match[0])

product_name = json_data['pdpData']['name']
mrp = json_data['pdpData']['price']['mrp']
selling_price = json_data['pdpData']['price']['discounted']

print('ProductName:', product_name)
print('MRP:', mrp)
print('SellingPrice:', selling_price)
```

Output:

```
ProductName: Roadster Men Charcoal Grey Sports Sandals
MRP: 1399
SellingPrice: 699
```

Comment: thanks it worked but a new issue occurs in flipkart section after running code for few time it sends `price` and `title` as `NoneType` how could i solve this or should i do the same with flipkart as you do with myntra or any other work around

Comment: Can you please share those `URL` of `flipkart section`, which gives you `price` and `title` as `None`.

Comment: use any flipkart product web it give the right result for some specific no. of retries but after that it start giving Nonetype  value same happen with amazon but i didn't include code for amzon on stackoveflow but  u can find this on this [link](https://pastebin.com/F2mWqn5j)

Comment: maybe `Flipkart` and `Amazon` detect that you are a bot, so they does not provide data. To avoid this situation add proper `headers`, `sleep` and `retry` in your code.